# Quartz/MYSQL A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source

Tags: mysql, quartz-scheduler

While trying to integrate Quartz scheduler into a spring application I'm trying to add persistence using `org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX` 
with the data store on mysql .

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = WDS

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.dontSetAutoCommitFalse = false
org.quartz.dataSource.WDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.WDS.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces = true
org.quartz.dataSource.WDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://url:port/DB?useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
org.quartz.dataSource.WDS.user = xxx
org.quartz.dataSource.WDS.password = xxx
org.quartz.dataSource.WDS.maxConnections = 4
```

Below is the error I get

> Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1469)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.<init>(Ljava/security/AlgorithmConstraints;)V
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:877)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:873)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:443)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

> Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'WatchdogsDS': java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:783)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3846)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.executeInLock(JobStoreTX.java:93)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeWithoutLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3785)
>       at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1524)
>       at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.getTrigger(QuartzScheduler.java:1499)
>       at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.getTrigger(StdScheduler.java:508)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.addTriggerToScheduler(SchedulerAccessor.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:235)
>       at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:510)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>       ... 29 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you mentioned can be caused by many reasons. First check the database version. I have problem with the latest version of mysql (8.0.11) which by default take Authentication Type "**caching_sha2_password**".

Changing to mysql version 5.7 resolved my problem which by default set Authentication Type to "**Standard**".

**N.B Don't forget to add required Administrative Roles and Schema Privileged**